# How to find first two digits in C

Tags: c

Hello I have code to find out the first two digits of a number and save them to a variable in C and the code only works for even length numbers.  I need something that will work for both even and odd length numbers.  The number I need for first2 is the first two numbers.

```
        long long int input = 6789466321
        first2 = input;
        while(first2 >= 100)
        {
            first2 = first2 / 100;
        }
```

Comment: "first two digits of a number and save them to a variable in C" do you refer to the variable input or?

Comment: Grab a pencil and paper. Figure out how you would do the math by hand. Once you've done that, convert it to code.

Comment: I assume that you meant it will only work for even _length_ numbers, not even numbers. The final digit shouldn't affect the outcome at all.

Comment: What should be the result with `input = -123`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Divide by 10 at a time instead of 100 so that you are only removing one digit each iteration.

Comment: Is there a way to find the first two digits without using a loop?

Answer (score 3):

A function to return the first 2 digits of a long given an input that is a positive number and at least 2 digits (e.g. 10 or above).

```c
int getFirst2Digits(long input)
{
    long local = input;

    while (local >= 100) 
    {
        local /= 10;
    }

    return local;
}
```

Comment: How did you come up with the 100?